# Appending a string with "<br>" tag doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I tried all methods possible and i simply can't add a break line inside a string which is stored in a variable and then used inside a specific function.

HTML code:

```
<body>
<p id="msg"></p>
</body>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {   
  if (index < message.length) {
    $(target).append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function () { showText(target, message, index, interval); }, interval);
  }
}
var x = "Hello there stranger!"+"<br>"+"How are you?";
$(function () {

  showText("#msg", x, 0, 130);   

});
</script>
```

It outputs the `<br>` tag as a string, instead to add a break line. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point is:

```
 [jQuery.append][1]
```

instead of:

```
 [jQuery.html][2]
```

I propose you:

```js
var showText = function (target, message, index, interval) {
  if (index < message.length) {
    // if special character: append the break element
    if (message[index] == '\n') {
      index++;
      $(target).append('<br/>');
    } else {
      // else: append text to the html
      $(target).html($(target).html() + message[index++]);
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
      showText(target, message, index, interval);
    }, interval);
  }
}

// use a special character instead of the break element
var x = "Hello there stranger!\nHow are you?";

$(function () {
  showText("#msg", x, 0, 130);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<p id="msg"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `parseHTML` method would help?

You would use it in your code above as follows:

```
var messageStr = $.parseHTML( message[index++] );
$(target).append(messageStr);
```

The `parseHTML` method converts the string into DOM nodes: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/